# Taleo Enterprise Edition - Hiring Status History

Tags: tcc, taleo

Either using TCC or by API, I would like to get the below details of a Candidate and Job Combination :

- What is the list of Hiring Statuses a Candidate has gone through so far (Step, Status)
- Also the update datetime of each such Step, Status

This will give me the trail of Step,Status and their updated Datetimes. 
My motive is that I want to know how much each step took as we hire candidates.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: The tag for TCC is reserved for the compiler ([Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the query:

```
    <projection>
        <field path="ProfileInformation, HistoryItems, ApplicationTrackingCSWItem.Step, Name"/>  
    </projection>
    <projection>
        <field path="ProfileInformation, HistoryItems, ApplicationTrackingCSWItem.Status, Name"/>  
    </projection>
```